# I have two csv files with one column each.

Tags: python, csv

One csv contains different categories name and other contains different places. I want to put a single category to all the places and concatenate them. How can i do this in python? 
csv 1 Column: categories(almost 400) 
csv 2 Column : Areas(almost 3000)

Comment: __csv1 column__ : electronics, hospitals, banks, footwears etc __csv2__column : area1, area2, area3, area4 etc. I want the results as **electronicsarea1, electronicsare2, electronicsarea3,electronicsarea4**

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('categories.csv') as cats, open('places.csv') as places, open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    places = list(csv.reader(places))
    outfile.writerow(["{}{}".format(cat, place) for cat, place in itertools.product(csv.reader(cats), places)])
```

Comment: @patrick: why don't you give it a try and see if it works within the memory footprint you want to limit it to